# Javascript is not working after implementing bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

Hy Guys

I have a problem with my Javascript. Since I implementet Bootstrap it won't work anymore. Even simple things like an alert with an onclick function won't work.

Here is my code:

**Implementet Scripts**

```
<link type="text/css" href="../CSS/main1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/main.js"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

**Simple HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <?php require 'scripts.php'; ?>
  </head>

  <header>
    <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
  </header>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid d-block d-sm-none">
      <!-- LAYOUT FOR MOBILE -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <button class="s-button" id="show-login" onclick="test()">Login</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <button  class="s-button">Register</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
function test(){
  alert('hallo');
}
```

I am programming since a bit know so it could be possible that I'm overlooking somthing simple but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Any errors thrown in browser dev tools console? Note that function name in `onclick` doesn't match what's in your script

Comment: Sorry I tried to implement the script right under the button with the script tag thats why it has an other name. But even when the function name is correct it won't work. Dev Console isn't showing any errors.

Comment: Are the JS folder and this HTML file in the same folder?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to put the JS function before the actual call in HTML. Also check your JS console to see if there are any errors there.

Comment: Thank you this is a good input but still not working. At least now I get the error test is not defined. But it is defined or not?

Comment: Hi I just ran this is my browser, and it is working - check your JS console to see if there are any errors there

Comment: What does your javascript look like? The error showing up in the console is: ReferenceError: test is not defined[Weitere Informationen] join.php:1:1
onclick
http://localhost/Design + Webseite/Webseite/HTML/join.php:1:1

Answer (score 0):

your javascript should load though, and you can just use this directly `<script src="../JS/main.js"></script>`
and ensure it is properly addressed i.e the JS is really uppercase.
and you could also put the main.js file above the bootstrap js file

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

1. Using `<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/main.js"></script>` as the link to your HTML, assuming the JS directory is in the same directory as your index.html file.
2. Put your links to external stuff in the HTML head. (It was unclear from your post whether or not you did.) You don't need to put them at the end of your HTML if you use `$(document).ready(function(){ //do stuff here });` which you should use anyway because jQuery is already included in your project since you're using Bootstrap. (You can declare your test function outside of the `document ready` call, and should.)
3. I am pretty sure the Bootstrap CSS link you were using was corrupted (or something), so I changed that to use MaxCDN.
4. My guess is your CSS isn't working either. Try changing something obvious with it to check. The '..' in a link means to move 'back' one directory, so chances are the browser is looking for this file somewhere that it doesn't exist.

Take a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) for more information about how to link to files, and consider trying an [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/).

Please let me know if you have any questions or if this doesn't work for you. When I started web development, I would spend ***hours*** trying to figure this stuff out.

**So your HTML would look like:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link type="text/css" href="../CSS/main1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- GOOGLE FONTS -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- JQUERY -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- FONT AWESOME -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/main.js"></script>
    <?php require 'scripts.php'; ?>
</head>

<header>
    <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
</header>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid d-block d-sm-none">
        <!-- LAYOUT FOR MOBILE -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <button class="s-button" id="show-login" onclick="test()">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <button class="s-button">Register</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**For bonus points:** if you need to see the console or to know anything about what is going on in either Firefox or Chrome, hit `ctrl shift i` and click around. If you think something has gone wrong, just hit the refresh button.

Answer (score 0):

So after spending another hour figuring out what is wrong with the code I found out that the code is correct form day one. The problem is that I am using Firefox Mobile Emulator to test the app and this won't show any alert window. When I deactivate the emulation and run the website as normal the alert box will show up as the button is clicked. So now I have installed Chrome and tested it there (also with the mobile emulator) and it works fine. So Firefox knows the problem (as forums post show) but they didn't fix it yet.

Anyway thank you all for the help.